# Mashable Like menu in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website in twitter bootstrap and want the same menu like mashable site.
can any one help me out with it.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) [Here's](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) the section of the bootstrap doc you're looking for

Comment: This may helps you

http://wsnippets.com/responsive-ajax-based-drop-menu-twitter-bootstrap-jquery-mysql-php/

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/xGf93/) a jsfiddle with a cleaned up copy of the navigation menu. You may need to open the fullscreen version to actually see the menu, here's the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/xGf93/embedded/result/). The hardest part will be going through the `5490` lines of css to find the stuff you actually need for the nav bar. Your best bet would be to start from scratch, and remember not every website is supposed to look the same! Good luck on your design.

Comment: Hey i can get the code from mashable too. but i want to know if this kind of menu works in Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: It's built using the twitter bootstrap, so yes it works with it.

Comment: i have just tried the css and still not working . the menu disturbed when it get responsive